# How to remove a space between mat-pagination and mat-table in Angular Material?

Tags: angular, angular-material

I have an Angular App with Material Design, where I am using pagination component from Angular Material lib.
No extra styles are applied.

[image]
On the screen you can see that there is a gap between a table and pagination. How can I rid of it? For example, when I choose the amount of users 5, the gap disappear.

**I used style="margin-top: -1px", but maybe there is a better way?**

**Maybe there is an option include the mat-paginator inside
mat-table ?**

HTML

```
<mat-table [dataSource]="data" [class.mat-elevation-z2]="true" style="overflow: hidden;">

  <ng-container matColumnDef="name">
    <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Nombres</mat-header-cell>
    <mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">
        <a (click)="redirectToUser(element.userId)">
            {{element.names}}
        </a>
    </mat-cell> 
  </ng-container>

  <ng-container matColumnDef="rol">
    <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Rol</mat-header-cell>
    <mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.rolDTO.name}} </mat-cell>
  </ng-container>

  <ng-container matColumnDef="username">
    <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Nombre del usuario</mat-header-cell>
    <mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">{{element.username}} </mat-cell>
  </ng-container>

  <ng-container matColumnDef="status">
      <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef class="cent">Estado</mat-header-cell>
      <mat-cell *matCellDef="let element" class="cent">
        <mat-icon *ngIf="element?.rolDTO?.status === 'A'" style="color: rgb(44, 136, 79)">check_circle_outline</mat-icon>
        <mat-icon *ngIf="element?.rolDTO?.status === 'I'" style="color: rgb(168, 25, 25)">highlight_off</mat-icon>
      </mat-cell>
  </ng-container>

  <mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="dataColumns"></mat-header-row>
  <mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: dataColumns;"></mat-row>


</mat-table>
<mat-paginator
style="overflow: hidden;"
[class.mat-elevation-z2]="true"
[showFirstLastButtons]="true"
(page)=               "paginate($event)"
[length]=             "pageConf.totalItems"
[pageSizeOptions]=    "pageConf.pageSize"
[pageSize]=           "pageConf.elementsPerPage"
</mat-paginator>
```

Comment: how about a running stackblitz example so that we can try it out without having to recreate your app for you?

Comment: Grey, I found a solution, but I couldnt answer on my own question cause I dont have enough of points. Thanks for your comment, will try it later

Comment: can you share you answer on a comment @MikeKylmäLampi